# Retrieving POST form input using Dart

Tags: html, dart

I am using IIS, so I need to avoid using port numbers. I have this index.html...

```
<body>

<div id="output"></div>
<p> </p>
<form action="verify.html" method="post">
<div>First name: <input type="text" name="first_name" required=""></div>
<div>Last name:  <input type="text" name="last_name" required=""></div>
<div><input type="submit" value="Add Name"></div>
</form>



</body>
```

All I want to do right now is display the user's input on verify.html. I wired a "verify.dart" to verify.html. I know that input can be retrieved in PHP 7 using

```
$firstName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'first_name');
```

Is there an analog to that code in the Dart SDK?

Comment: This can be done, but this is not a good use case for Dart. Dart is best used for Single Page Applications, not a page per view. http://dartdoc.takyam.com/docs/tutorials/forms/#submitting-a-form might provide some more insight.

Comment: I was hoping Dart could be an alternative to PHP, Javascript and ASP.NET/C#. I guess PHP 7 it is! I really don't want to have to monkey with Apache.

Comment: Dart can be a good alternative to PHP, but Dart can play it's strenghts in SPAs. Each view a different page (application) won't work well with Dart on the client. That would work with Dart only on the server, but for this scenario PHP is probably the better choice.